# PowerEdge T330 PCIe lane sizes?

Tags: dell-poweredge

I am looking at purchasing a Dell T330 Poweredge.  The Dell website datasheet indicates that the T330 has 4 PCIe slots internally, however it fail to mention if the slots are x8 lanes or other.  Does anyone have a T330 and know what is on the motherboard relative to PCIe edge slots?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in the user manual, rather than the datasheet.

```
Expansion bus specifications
PCI Express 
expansion slots
Specification
Slot 1 One full-height, half-length x8 PCIe Gen3 card slot connected to processor
Slot 2 One full-height, half-length x16 PCIe Gen3 card slot connected to processor
Slot 3 One full-height, half-length x1 PCIe Gen3 card slot connected to Platform Controller Hub (PCH)
Slot 4 One full-height, half-length x8 PCIe Gen3 card slot connected to PCH
```